# Some Features are Autocorrelated; my output variable is not

Tags: autocorrelation, model

I have 66 features. What does it mean if 5 or so features are highly autocorrelated (.99 at lag = 1)  with themselves but my output variable itself is not autocorrelated? Can I consider these subset of features to be irrelevant, and discard them?